# Dartanalyzer - exclude parts of libraries

Tags: bash, shell, dart, continuous-integration, drone.io

Hej, I am using drone.io together with a dart project. In my build script I have this cmd:

```
dartanalyzer lib/*.dart
```

It works fine and scans all dart files, but my `lib` directory contains also libraries that are split up in different files and there using the dart `part of` feature. When dartanalyzer scans these files it produces this error:

```
Only libraries can be analyzed.
lib/mylib.part.dart is a part and can not be analyzed.
```

and the build fails. Is there a way to exclude these files or hide these error? I named all files that are parts of a lib with `.part.dart`.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because you're asking DartAnalyzer to analyzer each of your .dart files individually, which means it's finding scripts that are just parts.

It should already follows link to other files, so you should be able to just pass it the entry point and it should automatically scan all the files that are referenced.

You can additionally pass `--show-package-warnings` to get have the analyzer includes results from the files you're importing with `import 'package:...';`

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer. Does this also scans files that are not explicitly referred using an `import` or `part` statement like files that I use as a isolate?

Comment: I updated my answer slightly; the `--package-root` switch doesn't do what I thought; it's just to let you tell the analyzer where it should resolve `package:` uris to. I don't believe you can make it scan arbitrary files that aren't included, unless you also include them in the command. So you could do `dartanalyzer bin\*.dart test\*.dart` to have it scan everything referenced by all of your bin scripts and tests (which hopefully will include all files!)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution in another direction: I just use bash to filter all files that end with `.part.dart`. Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -o xtrace
set -e

diranalyzer() {
  for f in $@
  do

    if [[ $f == *.part.dart ]]
    then
      continue
    fi

    dartanalyzer $f
  done
}

diranalyzer ./*.dart
```